# Wordpress - Adding icon to visual editor toolbar

Tags: wordpress

when i set up a new page in wordpress i'm able to switch between the html and visual editor. How can i alter the icons/functions which are shown in the visual editor's toolbar? I want to write a plugin which adds a function to the visual editor toolbar... I do not mean the "Upload/Insert" toolbar for media content, i mean the toolbar beyond the "Upload/Insert" toolbar...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for [**`TinyMCE`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE):

> WordPress is bundled with the open source HTML WYSIWYG editor [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) by [Moxiecode Systems, AB](http://moxiecode.com/).

---

Using this plugin you can re-arrange, add and remove buttons:

> #### [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)
>
> Enables the advanced features of TinyMCE, the WordPress WYSIWYG editor.

---

And in this WordPress Answers Q&A, you'll find how to do it by yourself:

> #### [How to add a shortcode button to the TinyMCE editor?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72394/12615)
>
> To add our button to the TinyMCE editor we need to do several things:
>
> 1. Add our button to the toolbar
> 2. Register a TinyMCE plugin
> 3. Create that TinyMCE plug-in which tells TinyMCE what to do when our button is clicked.